# AWS S3 consistency for inter-region locking

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a use case around guaranteeing *idempotent* behavior for client requests based on a client supplied *request_id*, across multiple AWS regions.

Therefore on request replay in case of timeouts or such, it is possible (though unlikely due to geo-affinity based routing) that another region receives the request.
The region that receives the replay needs to make a determination whether the request was received & is being processed by another AWS region.

From S3 documentation, I understand that S3 promises highly consistent read-after-write consistency i.e.

If I **GET** & don't find an object related to *request_id*, write/**PUT** an S3 object on *Region 1* & then start working on the request.

If the client retried and the request reached *Region 2*, would attempt to **GET** object related to *request_id* be guaranteed to see the PUT that was done in *Region 1*, *even if there was a region outage in Region 1* precisely after **PUT** was successful ?

Comment: Related to "If I GET & don't find an object related to request_id, write/PUT an S3 object on Region 1 & then start working on the request.", while S3 may be highly consistent, these two operations as a whole are not atomic. Consider using DynamoDB for [distributed locks](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/building-distributed-locks-with-the-dynamodb-lock-client/).

Comment: Thanks @jarmod, the documentation seems to indicate locking across 2 AZs in the a single AWS region & it isn't abundantly clear whether the solution works across multiple AWS regions.

Comment: That's just a specific test case that they've built to validate it, and so they can show you two independent clients and explain what the message protocol looks like.

Comment: makes sense ! so in reality this should work cross regions as well.